# I am still confused with free() and malloc()

Tags: c

In the below program, as far as in my knowledge once we allocate some memory then if we are chaging the address from 
`ptr to ptr++`, then when we are calling `free` with `ptr` i.e `free(ptr)`.
Then the program should crash.
But in this program works fine. 
How it works?
I am using Code::Bocks in Windows XP.
Please help me.

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(1);
    *ptr = 6;
    printf("The value at *ptr = %d \n", *ptr);
    ptr++;      //Now ptr is address has been changed
    free(ptr); // Program should crash here
    ptr = NULL;
    /* *ptr = 5;*/ // This statement is crashing
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that this code has 3 different cases of undefined behavior: 1) allocating 1 byte but storing sizeof(int) to that address, 2) attempting to free() an address that has never been passed to malloc/realloc/calloc, 3) `*ptr = 5;` trying to access the contents of a pointer that has been passed as parameter to free().

Comment: As you are on windows you could try http://drmemory.org/ - to give you more information, and debug/test memory related "tings".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absence of a crash does not necessarily mean your code is fine. On another platform, it will probably crash.
BTW: you should rather malloc(sizeof(int))

Comment: I think you are right. I was debugging the code by using the break-point it gave some warning

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of this program is **undefined** from the very moment that you store a value through an `int*` pointing to a single byte. There's no guarantee of a crash.

Specifically, it seems like your `free` doesn't (maybe can't) check its argument properly. Try running this program with a `malloc` debugging library.

Comment: OpenBSD has a great system for catching pointer misuse: http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=malloc.conf ; I generally catch things with the F, G, P, S, and Z options, sometimes going with multiple "<" to see if I can catch code that fails to check for malloc returns during runs (when I'm stressing other people's code)

Comment: @tbert: OpenBSD is a very feature-rich testing tool for Unix C programs ;)

Answer (score 1):

The program should not necessarily crash, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It works only due to luck; the code is still wrong.

To understand why, one first needs to be familiar with the implementation of the malloc library itself. malloc not only allocates the space it returned for you to use, it also allocates space for its own metadata that it uses to manage the heap (what we call the region of memory managed by malloc). By changing ptr and passing the wrong value to free, the metadata is no longer where free expected it, so the data it's using now is essentially garbage and the heap is corrupted.

This doesn't necessarily mean it'll crash due to say, a segfault, because it doesn't necessarily dereference a bad pointer. The bug still exists and will likely manifest itself in a longer program with more heap usage.